# How to run Jenkins scripted pipeline job on free slave?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run Jenkins scripted pipeline job at the specified slave at the moment when no other job is running on it.
After my job will be started, no other jobs should be performed on this slave, they will have to wait for my job ending running

All the tutorials that I found allowed me to run job on the node when it is free but did not protect me from launching other jobs on this node

Could you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: How about making the executor on the slave as one

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy I don't understand your idea. Can you describe your idea

Comment: Under Node Configuration of the slave, please select the executor to 1 usually the default is 2 meaning that 2 jobs can run in parallel. By making it 1 you are forcing it to cater to only one job at a time.

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy thank you for your advice but it's not my situation, I want to have specific behavior only for one job

Answer (score 1):

Because Pipeline has two Syntax, there are two ways to achieve that. For scripted pipeline please check the second one.

### Declarative

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent { label 'slave-node​' }
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
                sh '''
                '''
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        success {
            echo 'This will run only if successful'
        }
    }
}
```

### Scripted

```
node('your-node') {
  try {

    stage 'Build'
    node('build-run-on-this-node') {
        sh ""
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```